# Unable to record video using FFMPEG in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I have this animation generated using python. And once it generates, it's supposed to make a a video. I've gotten as far as creating the file, however I get a traceback error. And when I attempt to open the file, there's nothing in it.

Windows 10, running python 3.

I've messed with the PATH of ffmpeg, placed it directly in the folder. I removed a piece of code that generated a unique file name. And replaced it with a string. No file was being generated at all prior to that.

I also tried to change the codecs, still nothing.

The code that creates video:

```
plt.show()
animation.save('Output_Test.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
```

I expect to just get a video that says Output_Test.mp4. Which I do get, but it's empty.

Traceback Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Desktop\FranchiseRevenueComparison-master\FranchiseAnimation.py", line 277, in <module>
    animation.save('Output_Test.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1139, in save
    anim._init_draw()
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1732, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1755, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Desktop\FranchiseRevenueComparison-master\FranchiseAnimation.py", line 259, in animate
    self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 10, in draw
    _backend_tk.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, (0, 1, 2, 3))
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 77, in blit
    photoimage.blank()
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3548, in blank
    self.tk.call(self.name, 'blank')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "pyimage10"
```

RESOLVED:

I just had to reverse the order of plot and save.

Comment: Put the saving **before** `show`, else the figure will be closed already, when the animation is trying to save it. See, if that alone solves the issue; if not, a full [mcve] is needed.

Comment: Ah! That did it. Thank you!!